# Cytoscape: elements added inside 'render' event callback not showing in graph

Tags: javascript, visualization, graph-theory, cytoscape.js

I am using a listener on render callback, because originally I wanted to add a node for every midpoint of an edge. But since the midpoint position is {x: undefined, y: undefined} before graph is fully rendered ( I guess), this did not work.

So I am using `cy.one('render', callback)` and the callback is called directly upon rendering, but if elements are added inside this callback, these are only rendered to the graph when clicking on the map, even if `forceRender()` is called inside the callback.

Also, when logging `cy.renderer()` and then calling `renderer.redraw()` from the console, canvas is rerendered and elements are shown as well. Then, why is `forceRender()` not working?

I have created a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx0a2y5d/166/) that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested with timeout functions and found that apparently, `forceRender()` is not working inside the 'render' event callback, probably to not cause any loops.

The solution to this problem is to set a timeout before calling `forceRender()`:

```
cy.one('render', function (e) {
    console.log('event', e)
    cy.collection('edge').forEach(function (element, index) {
        let p = element.midpoint();
        add_node('newnode' + index, 'newnode' + index, index);
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        cy.forceRender();
    }, 0);
})
```